# Error to connect SQL Database at hosting website

Tags: c#, asp.net

did anybody host asp.net website with sql database? 
I couldn't integrate my database connection with .mdf sql file (in my App_Data folder).

Is there anything need to change my data connection string (`connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\example.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"`).

My host website: www.hostgator.com

It's really helpful if u give me proper suggestions step by step.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Database name is missing your Connection String :

Change as below:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\example.mdf;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Integrated Security=True;"
```

Answer (score 0):

your connection string (`connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\example.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"`) is the one you use when running locally. change it to the connection string that your hosting site gave you. it is usually on the database information.

Answer (score 0):

After initial setup has been done, test your connecting weather it is successful or not then

write your connecting string as below:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\example.mdf;Initial Catalog=yourDBname;Integrated Security=True;"
```

Where yourDBname is the name of your database that you have already given.

Hope this helps
Regards, 
Rubel